# How do I save case sensitive data in only one of the table columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, case-sensitive

I am using SQL Server database to store information for my application.

One of the columns in a table has to store the case sensitive data.

How should I set this one specific column in the table to be case sensitive?

**EDIT:**

1) I use linq to sql for the query 
2) I store in the DB info that mast be Case sensative

Comment: What does your data currently look like in the database? I have never seen a database change case before.

Comment: I've provided an answer below, please check out the link I've provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the collation at the column level and set it to a **case sensitive** collation.

Following script shows two different ways.

1. Setting a collation during table creation.
2. Setting a collation for an existing column using ALTER statement.

In the collation `Latin1_General_CS_AS`, **CS** stands for **`CASE SENSITIVE`**

[**Read here to know more about SQL Server Collation.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx)

### Set collation during create table

#### Create script with collation

```
CREATE TABLE textvalue
(
     caseinsensitive  VARCHAR(30)
  ,  casesensitive    VARCHAR(30)
        COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
);
```

### Set collation during alter table

#### Create script with no collation

```
CREATE TABLE textvalue
(
     caseinsensitive  VARCHAR(30)
  ,  casesensitive    VARCHAR(30)
);
```

#### Alter script to set the collation

```
ALTER TABLE textvalue
    ALTER COLUMN casesensitive VARCHAR(30)
    COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

### Sample that demonstrates with test data

#### Populate table script

```
INSERT INTO textvalue (caseinsensitive, casesensitive) VALUES
  ('test', 'Test'),
  ('Test', 'test'),
  ('TeSt', 'TeSt');
```

#### Script searching on case sensitive column: [**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ac27/2)

```
SELECT  caseinsensitive
    ,   casesensitive  
FROM    textvalue 
WHERE   casesensitive = 'test';
```

*Output*:

```
CASEINSENSITIVE  CASESENSITIVE
---------------  -------------
Test             test
```

#### Script searching on case insensitive column: [**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ac27/3)

```
SELECT  caseinsensitive
    ,   casesensitive  
FROM    textvalue 
WHERE   caseinsensitive = 'test';
```

*Output*:

```
CASEINSENSITIVE  CASESENSITIVE
---------------  -------------
test             Test
Test             test
TeSt             TeSt
```

Comment: I am sorry but I run the following scrip on my table`ALTER TABLE textvalueALTER COLUMN casesensitive VARCHAR(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;` vut nothig happen still get my data as lower and not case sensative

Comment: :) sure I change the the vlues to my value but still as I say I use linw to sql and I get lower results

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer! Check out the link below!

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/

The answer below, is certainly an alternative, but you can indeed set a case sensitive parameter on an individual sql server column.

Another thing you can do, is compare the values against MD5 hashes, as the MD5 hash is unique for each string.

```
// md5 hash is unique for TEST, and test
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(column) = MD5("TEST") // Hash : 033bd94b1168d7e4f0d644c3c95e35bf
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(column) = MD5("test") // Hash : 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

You may have issues with indexing, but it's definitely worth a shot :) Alternatively, you could store an md5 hash next to the column, such as column_md5, and run searches based on that column. The only drawback there, will be the fact that you need to store the hashed value with every update to the column

Comment: If you were running a search solely on that column, yes, however, if you have another criteria, such as AND parent_id = 1 that is indexed, the hit wouldn't be nearly as bad. I will agree with you though, that by doing this, you lose indexing on the column you're doing the operation on

Comment: I don't know that much about sql server, the databases I work with are case sensitive by default, and do allow configuring case sensitive matching per column. I don't believe the sql server developers haven't thought this thing through...

Comment: I am using Linq to sql so I cannt do that